# Alert Dialog with if statement got an error 'has leaked window DecorView that was originally added here'

Tags: android, onclick, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener, dismiss

I tried to show `alertdialog` in some condition(In codes, it's MyIfStatement).

I made `MyDialog` in `onCreate` and tried to show `onClick` when press the confirm button in specific condition.

I got an error named `has leaked window DecorView that was originally added here`.

I found that we must dismiss dialog before activity end.

Could you tell me what is the problem of my codes?

My code is below.

```
public class BaseWidgetConfigureActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    private static final String TAG = BaseWidgetConfigureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    AlertDialog MyDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ConfirmButton = findViewById(R.id.widget_confirm_button);
        CancelButton = findViewById(R.id.widget_cancel_button);

        ConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        CancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        MyDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseWidgetConfigureActivity.this)
                .setMessage("My message.")
                .setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.confirm_button:
                if (MyIfStatement){
                    MyDialog.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.cancel_button:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

In positive button `onClick`, I tried

1)

```
onStop();
dialog.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
finish();
```

2)

```
onPause();
dialog.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
finish();
```

3)

```
dialog.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
finish();
```

In negative button `onClick`, I tried

1)

```
dialog.cancel();
finish();
```

2)

```
dialog.cancel();
```

and so on.

Comment: From where you set `MyIfStatement` to true?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Yes, I checked.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I have few more functions and onProgressChanged, onStartTrackingTouch, onStopTrackingTouch related to seekbar. Should I dismiss all?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class BaseWidgetConfigureActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = BaseWidgetConfigureActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    AlertDialog MyDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ConfirmButton = findViewById(R.id.widget_confirm_button);
        CancelButton = findViewById(R.id.widget_cancel_button);

        ConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        CancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        MyDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseWidgetConfigureActivity.this)
                .setMessage("My message.")
                .setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss(); //1.
                        startActivity(new
                                Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.confirm_button:
                if (MyIfStatement){
                    MyDialog.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.cancel_button:
                dialog.dismiss();//2.
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                dialog.dismiss();//3.
                finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        dialog.dismiss(); //4.
        super.onPause();
    }
 }
```

you must dismiss dialog before all finishes or intents.

Comment: I tried with your comment. The error disappear but the dialog does not show. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("Write your Message Here....");
builder.setCancelable(true);

builder.setPositiveButton(
    "Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

builder.setNegativeButton(
    "No",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: I got the same error where I insert your code in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing the application or activity context, where the dialog destroys will have issues. Create a singleton/Custom class to handle the dialog context.

Handle the context if not null and then initialize the alert dialog else return the flow.